# how to use tinymce content.css in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, asset-pipeline

I need to provide tinymce a css file to take the styles from, but if I set in any file something like

```
body{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

it will set the webapp's body to that style and not only tinymce's input box.

How do I give tinymce a content.css file with the asset pipeline involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the proper format for this is to write

```
body.mceContentBody {
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

or in TinyMCE 4.x (class name changed)

```
body.mce-content-body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

and the tinymce (if using the gem) should be

```
<%= tinymce :content_css => asset_path('application.css')%>
```