# Configure tinymce-rails to use a different font family by default

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have seen a few examples of this for configuring normal tinymce, however not in the context of the tinymce-rails gem? I would imagine it is just a setting in tinymce.yml but haven't been able to find it. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

To get content_css working the answer here helped:

[how to use tinymce content.css in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099629/how-to-use-tinymce-content-css-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with tinymce-rails.
But for the regular tinymce there is a setting which allows you to add a custom css file to the editor content (to the editors iframe). This param is called [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css).